# How can I map the docky anchor button so that it will launch the unity dash?

Tags: docky

Example of a Docky Dock

[image]

I have the Docky dock on my desktop.  It has an anchor logo button (as seen on the left side image of the link above) that brings up the Docky settings.  I want to map it so that it opens my dash instead.   I believe I can do this through gconf and by setting the docky button to either my super key or the necessary path required to open the dash function (but I do not know this path or how to code a button to a keyboard key).

**How can I map the docky anchor button so that it will launch the unity dash** (as similar to when you simply tap the super key)**?**

Comment: What if you make a .desktop file to launch the Dash (whichever command it is, i don't use Unity) and then remove the anchor to make space for your new launcher? just a thought..

Comment: This worked splendidly!  Thanks for thinking outside the box!

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.desktop` file, in which you use the command to Open the Dash remove the Docky anchor and place the `.desktop`file you made in it's place.

Comment: Could you provide a bit deeper step by step instructions?

Answer (score 0):

```
gconftool –type String –set /apps/docky-2/Docky/Items/DockyItem/DockyItemCommand \
```

“xdotool key super”

Comment: You need to install `xdotools` first.